# Display message "Connect to customer care" if bot isn't able to answer on 3 consecutive attempts...dotnet core 3.1...............MS Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I have a bot which displays "No answers found" if the question that user has asked isn't present in the knowledge base.

I want to display a different message (e.g Contact support desk on some phone number 123456789)  if the bot isn't able to answer on 3 consecutive attempts.

Something like as shown in the below image:
[image: Image for reference]

Comment: Why don't you just hold a variable called 'wrong_answers' in conversation state  and when it hits 3, divert to a different portion of the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer without knowing exactly how you have QnA Maker set up, but what @JJ_Wailes suggested is the way to go. You need to keep track of the number of wrong answers, and then provide your alternative default message. To give myself more flexibility, I have always created my own default response logic instead of relying on QnA Maker. I'm going to make some assumptions that you are already good making the QnA Maker calls and dealing with user and conversation state. Instead of relying on the QnA Maker default answer, I check for the confidence score returned and create my own message activities for those cases. For simplicity I'm going to ignore prompts. Here is a sample of my typical QnA Maker flow. Unfortunately I have developed in nodejs only, but I think this should be similar enough that you can adapt for dotnet.

```js
var MINIMUM_SCORE = 50;
const conversationData = await this.dialogState.get(context, {});
// Will use conversationData.qnaFailCount to track consecutive wrong answers

// Make the initial call
var qnaResult = await QnAServiceHelper.queryQnAService(activity.text);
var qnaAnswer = qnaResult[0].answer;

// Apply a confidence filter
if (qnaResult[0].score > MINIMUM_SCORE) {
  outputActivity = MessageFactory.text(qnaAnswer);
  conversationData.qnaFailCount = 0; // Reset counter when answer found
} else {
  // If low confidence, increment counter
  conversationData.qnaFailCount += 1;
  if (conversationData.qnaFailCount < 3) {
    outputActivity = MessageFactory.text(defaultAnswer);
  } else {
    // Send the escalation message for every consecutive "no answer" starting at 3
    outputActivity = MessageFactory.text(escalation);
  }
}
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context); // Don't forget to save state!
return outputActivity;
```

So now you will increment the counter for each answer that is not found and reset it whenever an answer is found. In this way it will continue to give the escalation mesasge for the 4th, 5th, etc. query with no answer. Since you are using conversation state, when the user leaves the site and comes back, they will have a new conversation and the process will start over.

Note that in the event you are using this within Microsoft Teams, that is treated as one long conversation, so the message wouldn't reset even after multiple days, only with a correct answer. It seems like this is not an MS Teams use case but I wanted to mention that.